# Cypress: get nested components using id in Next Js

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress, tdd

I am going to write tests in cypress. The component which I going to test is below mentioned.

```
import Layout from "../../components/layout"
import ActionAreaCard from '../../components/card'
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <Layout id='layout'>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <ActionAreaCard
                       id='action-card-submit'
                       title='Submit Damage Report'
                       href="/view/data-submission"
                       imagePath='/assets/images/car-damage.jpg'
                     />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <ActionAreaCard
                       id='action-card-view'
                       title='View Damage Reports'
                       href="/view/view-reports"
                       imagePath='/assets/images/damage-report.jpg' />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

I need to test navigation after clicking 'ActionAreaCard'. I have done it so far as follows.

```
it('should navigate to the data submissions page', () => {
    // Start from the index page
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/')

    // Find a button with an href attribute containing "/view/data-submission" and click it
    cy.get('a[href*="/view/data-submission"]').click()
  })
```

But I need to find the component by 'id'.
[image: This is the screenshot of webage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the `id`.

```js
cy.get('#action-card-submit').click()
```

You can directly use the text to identify and click the element as well.

```js
cy.contains('Submit Damage Report').click()
cy.contains('View Damage Reports').click()
```

Comment: AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: #action-card-submit, but never found it.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options when searching by `id`

- use the attribute syntax `cy.get('id=["action-card-submit"]')`
- use shorthand `cy.get('#action-card-submit')`, but this can fail if special characters are in the id

Comment: Not worked.. 
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: #action-card-submit, but never found it.